# Site Collection Features Giving Error

Tags: 2010

I am relatively new to SharePoint, and I have tried about everything that internet says to do....  but failed.

Within Sharepoint 2010, I did do an install, and the SharePoint Central Administration installs to the C drive.  I created a new site  on drive E.  With that being said, let the problem begin...

When I try to go to most Site Administration features, Site Collection Navigation, etc on , I get the error that basically gives me a long number to no where is what it has felt like the last 2 days.

I do believe after everything I have read, this is also hindering me from seeing the Business Data Web Parts as well.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Anything in the event log? What about the ULS logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the SharePoint server,  all the actual errors are logged onto ULS log (14\LOGS) directory.

- Download ULS Viwer: [ULS Viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458052/ULS-Log-Viewer)
- Open the tool and connect it to open the current ULS logs.
  [image: Open Log]
- If you have opened this tool from server,  you can choose first option (Use ULS feed from default log-file directory), this will determine the current ULS directory and open the current log file.
- Perform the operation that generates error.  Copy the long number (known as correlation ID).
- Filter your log file in the ULS Viweer for this correlation ID and you will be able to see all activity with detailed error messages.

This should help you in knowing what is going on wrong with your SharePoint server,  you can google for this error message and get resolution.

another option is to use PowerShell,

If you have a multi server environment,  you can consolidate logs from all server related to this correlation Id using [Merge-SPlogfile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721%28v=office.15%29.aspx) command in SharePoint PowerShell,  this command will require you passing a path for the file where you want to write all the information and correlation ID.

I hope this gives you some idea on how to use that big number :)

Comment: I have attempted to put the numbers in and did everything most everyone said.  Still no luck.

Comment: Do you have a multi server enviornment?,  log file entries are distributed between your Web Front Ends,  i hope you have admin access to your SharePoint servers

Comment: The good thing is I have complete access to the servers and applications, as for a multi server.  not at all, just one app server and one sql server.

Comment: Ooh in that case it is fairly easy.  Just open the logs from your app server in the lob viewer. Perform operation and filter the log for correlation if

Comment: Thank you Sudhir, I did find in the logs the issue and was able to research for the following URL:

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/91004586-8982-4ca8-84de-f868a26d0cc5/cannot-find-contentplaceholder?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Thank you for your help.